# Karate DSL: Getting connection timeout error

Tags: karate

I am working on automating a API which is hosted in China server and when I send a request it throws me timeout exception ( `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException`).

My feature file:

```
Background: 
  * url 'http://myurl'
  * configure connectTimeout = 500000

Scenario: Get Client details
  Given path '/clients'
  And header Authorization = 'sdssSSLwWDSD'
  When method get
  Then match response.client_id == 'TestId'
```

Error details:

```
11:22:30.347 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://myurl.com][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
11:22:30.365 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://myurl.com][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
11:22:30.365 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://myurl.com
11:22:30.384 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to myurl.com/54.223.191.33:443
11:22:30.384 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to myurl.com/54.223.191.33:443 with timeout 500000
11:22:51.407 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connect to myurl.com/54.223.191.33:443 timed out. Connection will be retried using another IP address
11:22:51.407 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to myurl.com/52.80.167.86:443
11:22:51.408 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to myurl.com/52.80.167.86:443 with timeout 500000
11:23:12.438 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
11:23:12.439 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
11:23:12.440 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://myurl.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
11:23:12.440 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to myurl.com [myurl.com/54.223.191.33, myurl.com/52.80.167.86] failed: Connection timed out: connect, http call failed after 42094 milliseconds for URL: https://myurl.com/tnc/v1/tnc/all
11:23:12.441 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to myurl.com:443 [myurl.com/54.223.191.33, myurl.com/52.80.167.86] failed: Connection timed out: connect
11:23:12.601 [Finalizer] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager is shutting down
11:23:12.601 [Finalizer] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager shut down
HTML report: (paste into browser to view) | Karate version: 0.9.4
```

What I have tried yet:
I tried to configure timeout to max as below:

```
 * configure connectTimeout = 500000
```

It didn't work.

However, the same request when tried from Postman, works fine and I get response within 2000 ms.

Not sure where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have a corporate HTTP proxy.

Refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

```
* configure proxy = 'http://my.proxy.host:8080'
```