# Flaky SocketTimeoutExceptions with Karate tests

Tags: karate

Fairly new to Karate. I'm trying to debug a few tests that have been intermittently failing with SocketTimeoutExceptions. I usually see something like:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: -unknown-:16 - 
create-identity.feature:23 - 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at ✽.* def associatedUserIdentity = call read('classpath:services/shared/create-identity.feature')
```

The strange part is that the tests pass on the first run, but if I repeat the tests they start hanging and I see these errors.

We have `connectTimeout` and `readTimeout` set to 30000 if that's useful.

The endpoints return 200 OK within a couple of seconds when I manually test them using a REST client so I'm thinking there might be something wrong with our Karate configuration.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We also faced this issue, and as it a very sporadic issue, it's hard to share steps to reproduce.
A work around that worked for us in most of the cases is to reduce the the `threadCount` in the runner to 1:
`final Results stats = AgentRunner.parallel(getClass(), 1, KARATE_OUTPUT_PATH);`

Comment: really sounds like you have a proxy that is throttling connections

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this before. The only thing I can think of is that maybe you have a proxy involved.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59678094/143475

If you are still stuck you have to provide a way to replicate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT: try switching to `karate-jersey` instead of `karate-apache` to see if that makes a difference.