# Karate scripts with API request to Splunk server works fine on MAC but fails on windows & pipeline[Alpine linux]

Tags: karate

We are attempting to extract logs from Splunk server using karate exposed endpoint, however stuck with ConnectTimeoutException from Windows & Pipeline[Alpine Linux].

We tried replicating the same scenario on MAC from the same karate scripts and it works fine without any issues. It also works fine through postman on a windows machine.

I did go through this documentation, but unable to figure out a solution to get around this. Requesting your advice on this.

Here is the CURL command we are executing,

```html
curl --location --request POST 'https://abc.splunkcloud.com:8089/services/search/jobs?output_mode=json' \

--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \

--header 'Authorization: Bearer {token}' \

--data-urlencode 'urlencode=search' \

--data-urlencode 'search=search "3389c1f0-abf0-11ed-b800-6aa993319721"| search "system Calling Customer Onboarding API with request"' \

--data-urlencode 'index=log | tojson'
```

**Error message below on windows machine & pipeline -**

10:23:41.345 org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to abc.splunkcloud.com:8089 [bendigoadelaide.splunkcloud.com/34.149.165.51] failed: Read timed out, http call failed after 5232 milliseconds for url: https://abc.splunkcloud.com:8089/services/search/jobs?output_mode=json

Karate script below, this is even without passing a bearer token we get direct error message above,

```
Scenario: Verify the connectivity to splunk server from windows
Given url 'https://bendigoadelaide.splunkcloud.com:8089/services/search/jobs?output_mode=json'
When method post
```

Comment: most likely because of an HTTP proxy involved, sorry you have to figure this out yourself https://stackoverflow.com/a/59678094/143475