# Karate throwing error in Gloo API gateway and there is no proxy

Tags: karate

Our All new API's are in Gloo micro Gateway, so when I am trying to connect it with karate, it is throwing the error "java.net.socketexception" but the same thing is working fine in postman.

There is no proxy set as such.

So in Karate do we have a use case where we have successfuly triggered the API behind the gloo micro gateway?

This a blocker for us for all the API in GCP. Any insights will be very helpfull.

The API behind Gloo network should work properly in Karate

Comment: okay, I see you have "no proxy". I will have to give up here. karate should work for any API it can connect to, gloo or whatever should not matter. maybe someone else can help you - but I have a feeling you have some networking weirdness going on. pretty sure you have to figure this out yourself.

Comment: Thanks Peter, just to add here,  the error says  java.net.socketexception: connection reset,  so does this relate to proxy ? I got an indication that there is no proxy but I am so confused.

Comment: I honestly don't know. I personally think it is a proxy. I'm sure you understand that it is impossible for me to figure anything out without having access to your API. if it was public, I would sort this out in 5 minutes. maybe you have to work with your IT folks.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I will let you know how it goes, but anyways thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: Thanks Peter, Calling the End point with rest assured is working perfectly fine, so no proxy issues there. This is what I am getting .... [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset...    anything with the Karate?

Comment: your karate test is WRONG then :) what do you want me to do. last guess, see whether you used `http` instead of `https` by mistake (or vice versa). and try `* configure ssl = true`

Comment: :) I have around 500 test scenarios written in karate, with around 20 API's all are working fine, this is the new one on gloo Api gateway on GCP which is giving me stress :(, I am helpless here :(

Comment: I found a similar old issue here, but no resolution    https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1081

Comment: Another observation, In rest Assured I have to pass relaxedHTTPSValidation(SSL) in rest assured  which is smilar to * configure ssl = true in karate.  But One my of peer doesnt even have to pass relaxedHTTPSValidation(SSL) in rest assured still it works for it.  In karate if dont pass * configre ssl = true it give SSL handshake issue, if I pass * configure ssl = true,  then SocketConnection issue.   is this something related to karate version or something? may be guess?

Comment: look did you try checking if your URLs are using `http` instead of `https` ?

Comment: I tried both,  but the url are using HTTPS

Comment: that's it, I'm done here. if your company is happy to pay hourly consulting rates, I can sign an NDA and get on a call. all the best. maybe this is the universe telling you to use rest-assured or postman. I would really like to improve karate or fix the docs if applicable. the rest is up to you

Comment: Thanks Peter, i would really recommend you to run atleast one karate use case with gloo api gateway on Gcp. If that doesn’t works for you then I think you need to fix karate. Thats absolutely new tech stack and many organisations are heading to that directions. As always thanks for your support

Comment: do me a favor, create a test end point using a personal gcp account and gloo and let me know. I don't have the time to set up gloo and gcp

Comment: Sorry Peter I dont have gcp account and much exposure on gloo api. My organisation is started using this just now. They indicated that all the Apis will be on gloo in future,Lets see how it goes, But I really dont want to get away from karate :(, I am in love with it :( :(

Comment: which location are you in. if you don't want to post here, submit a request at https://www.karatelabs.io/contact-us and I can get on a call if you are ok to share your screen and walk through the details

Comment: Sent my details thanks

Comment: ALl fixed Peter, there was a strict policy not to bypass the SSL, so * configure ssl = true was throwing the error. So I need to import some certs in the JVM and make the  * configure ssl = false in the feature file for that particular API  ( since other API need to bypass ssl so I havnt changed  * configure ssl = true]  in config file). Thanks Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this kind of issue is because you have an HTTP proxy or because there is no network connectivity to the server. For proxy configuration, refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59678094/143475

For network issues please take the help of your local IT folks.

There is a rare chance that the server is very strict about certificates even if you [`* configure ssl = true`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configure). In that case, read on.

For the benefit of others, pasting the solution from the comments thread:

> there was a strict policy not to bypass the SSL, so * configure ssl = true was throwing the error. So I need to import some certs in the JVM and make the * configure ssl = false in the feature file for that particular API ( since other API need to bypass ssl so I havnt changed * configure ssl = true] in config file).

For those looking for details on how to configure certificates in Karate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#x509-certificate-authentication

Note that `* configure ssl = false` (or `true`) can be done any time within a test. This means even if you choose to set it "globally" in `karate-config.js` you could over-ride it in specific `Feature`-s or `Scenario`-s.