Karate - framework setup from scratch
I tried to setup karate from scratch using the below configuration in my corporate network. When I try to execute the simple feature, I am getting the below exception.
Feature :

Exception :

But when I try to execute the same using postman, I am getting proper response.

When I try to execute after executing in postman, the request is passing with the same configuration.

Config file:

Configuration -
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>11.0.18</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.11.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0</maven.surefire.version>
    <karate.version>1.4.1</karate.version>
</properties>

I tried all the SSL and proxy options that is provided as reference in stack overflow. Even tried to get assistance from ChatGPT. If anyone has faced the same issue and found any solution?
Kindly please assist.

I'm sorry - you have to figure this out on your own, I can only point you to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76403461/143475 - see if some other API works and try from somebody else's machine to narrow down the cause
